# Wix Script Installation - Not happening Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, wix, windows-installer

We are using Wix script for installation through Jenkins. Ours is 64-bit OS. If executed through command prompt Windows\system32 desktop folder is dispalyed as C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\ which will do the installation properly. But if we run through Jenkins Desktop folder is C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop\ . In later case installation and shortcut creation is improper. How to overcome this ?? What might be the reason?? Thank you in advance for any help. Here is the WIX SCRIPT

```
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
 <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE" Version="1.0.0.0" 
          Language="1033" Name="Product" Manufacturer="ABC">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" 
             Comments="Windows Installer Package"/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Product">
          <Component Id="XYZ" Guid="*">
            <File Id="XYZ.exe" Source="D:\Repo\Solution\XYZ\bin\Debug\XYZ.exe">
            </File>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

        <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="XYZ">
          <Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts" Guid="*">
            <Shortcut Id="ApplicationShortcut1" Name="XYZ" 
                      Description="Product Shortcut"
                      Target="[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]XYZ.exe" 
                      WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\XYZ"
                      Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>                           


  <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="XYZ"/>
    <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcuts"/>
  </Feature>

  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
</Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Jenkins is running as `SYSTEM` account. If you want to run Jenkins as user XXXXX so that the installation goes fine as it went while running as user XXXXX, then just try running Jenkins with the same user. To do that, go to `Run` > type `services.msc` > select `Jenkins` > (Right-click and select) `Properties` > Click on `Log On` tab > Select `This account`

Now enter the user name with which you want to run Jenkins and its password. Now restart Jenkins. You can now give a try to your WiX script.